# Python Beautiful Soup - Getting input value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My plan is to be able to grab the _AntiCsrfToken by using Bs4.

I have this HTML where my HTML comes from [image]

and what I have written in the code is

```
token = soup.find('input', {'name':'_AntiCsrfToken'})['value'])
print(token)
```

but it gives me a error saying

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HelloWorld.py", line 67, in <module>
    print(soup.find('input', {'name':'_AntiCsrfToken'})['value'])
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1292, in find
    l = self.find_all(name, attrs, recursive, text, 1, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

I quite dont understand if I have done it right or not. I do think I did it right but maybe I need to find it before from form-id than just go into hidden directly ?

Comment: it looks like you use a method on `soup` which then calls `self.find_all` but claiming that `self` is a string which is very highly out of the ordinary, have you tried updating bs4 to latest version?

Comment: Hmm. Well, I dont know if its possible to updating but I have done ```pip install beautifulsoup4``` but it says I already have it installed so I assume I do have the latest version. I also did install it few days ago.

Comment: just try [`pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4`](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#upgrading-packages) although it should suggest that if it detects an available update. I will take a look at the source code see if I can figure out what's going on

Comment: Oh well. It was the latest version already. I could have give you the source code but I don't know where to share it since its abit long. Any suggestions where? @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen

Comment: I meant look at `bs4.element` line 1292 but there is no way `self` could accidentally be a `str`.  are you able to use `soup.find_all`? can you post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure where the error lies for you but I have made a little html file and put it on my server and I have no problem copying and pasting your code..

The only noticeable difference (if you have not done it) is that I am using requests to parse the html to BS4

I think maybe it is a parsing problem.

HTML

```
<html>

<form action="process">
<input type="hidden" name="_AntiCsrfToken" value="5435434354353453545">

</form>
</html>
```

Python:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests

r = requests.get('http://maffaz.com/so.html')
html_bytes = r.text
soup = bs4(html_bytes, 'lxml')
token = soup.find('input', {'name':'_AntiCsrfToken'})['value']
print(token)
```

returns:

```
5435434354353453545
```

Also you do not need

```
{'name':'_AntiCsrfToken'}
```

so:

```
token = soup.find('input')['value']
```

Will work

Comment: I already have the latest version and I still got the same issue.

Comment: Can you post more of the code.  Either an MCVE here or the full code on github/ pastebin.. preferably an MCVE

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<html>
<input type="hidden" name="_AntiCsrfToken" value="5435434354353453545">
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
csrf = soup.select_one('input[name=_AntiCsrfToken]')['value']
print(csrf)
```

Output: `5435434354353453545`