# Getting value from hidden form with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website which has the following in its HTML

```
<form id="__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" action="#" method="post">
   <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="LOUesP09TLS3suKJk4dF5hIxeo-LmDWLxX8xqwIHYnj-JqR29qDcGA_mtHXvyZIej83qG3FfBBs2nuzk1EY6onTuszY1">
</form>
```

and I'm trying to extract the `value` with BeautifulSoup using

```
page = urllib2.urlopen(LOGIN_URL)
# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable `soup`
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

form = soup.find("form", {"id": "__AjaxAntiForgeryForm"})
```

which correctly returns

```
<form action="#" id="__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="zd7XHXyVs7EgqObLzIfm9k4bw1cWfcddhfDZ9Mp8TibBaAJUz-yAp1ZBuKS1iJtEAvmI1WG_EYnbmXBnWzuKWJxfl8U1"/></form>
```

My problem is in extracting just the value from that tag.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001678/python-beautiful-soup-form-input-parsing) answer and using

```
form = soup.find("form", {"id": "__AjaxAntiForgeryForm"})['value']
```

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46028156/python-beautiful-soup-getting-input-value?rq=1) answer but it just returns `KeyError: 'value'`.

I could convert it to a string and use regex to extract the value but that seems clunky and there must be a cleaner way of doing it using BeautifulSoup.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.attrs['value']`

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """<form id="__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" action="#" method="post">
   <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="LOUesP09TLS3suKJk4dF5hIxeo-LmDWLxX8xqwIHYnj-JqR29qDcGA_mtHXvyZIej83qG3FfBBs2nuzk1EY6onTuszY1">
</form>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
form = soup.find("form", {"id": "__AjaxAntiForgeryForm"})
print( form.input.attrs['value'] )
```

**Output:**

```
LOUesP09TLS3suKJk4dF5hIxeo-LmDWLxX8xqwIHYnj-JqR29qDcGA_mtHXvyZIej83qG3FfBBs2nuzk1EY6onTuszY1
```

Comment: This works if I want to get hidden contents. I want to delete  all the hidden tags from the HTML content and save the HTML content on database. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<form id="__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" action="#" method="post">
           <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="LOUesP09TLS3suKJk4dF5hIxeo-LmDWLxX8xqwIHYnj-JqR29qDcGA_mtHXvyZIej83qG3FfBBs2nuzk1EY6onTuszY1">
        </form>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
value = soup.find('input', {'name':'__RequestVerificationToken'})['value']
print value
```

Answer (score 0):

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url1 = "LOGINURL"

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(url1, "html.parser")

form1 = soup1.find('input', {'name':'__RequestVerificationToken'})

print(form1.get('value'))